# pandas groupby() with custom aggregate function to concatenate columns then rows using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Suppose I have a dataframe like:

```
 Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4
 1          I          am         abc
 3          on         weekend    holidays
 1          I          do         business
 2          I          am         xyz
 3          I          do         nothing
 2          I          do         job
```

after applying the groupby() using pandas expected result is:

```
Column1    Column2
1          I am abc I do business
2          I am Xyz I do job
3          On weekend holidays I do nothing
```

The required aggregation is applicable first for the column than by rows.

How it can be performed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
df['newcol'] = df.apply(lambda x: " ".join(x[1:]), axis=1)
df.groupby('Column1').agg({'newcol': lambda x: " ".join()})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) first and then aggregate `join` in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index('Column1')
         .stack()
         .groupby("Column1")
         .agg(' '.join)
         .reset_index(name='Column2'))
print (df1)
   Column1                           Column2
0        1            I am abc I do business
1        2                 I am xyz I do job
2        3  on weekend holidays I do nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? First combine the words of the columns you want into new column then use `groupby` to join them together.

`df['new_col'] = df['Column2'] + str(" ") + df['Column3'] + str(" ") + df['Column4']`

`df.groupby('Column1')['new_col'].agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str)))`

```
Column1
1              I am abc I do business
2                   I am xyz I do job
3    on weekend holidays I do nothing
Name: new_col, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try as follows

```
def apply_union(x):
    ## join multiple columns to single sting in row
    x = x.apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
    ## concat rows to single string
    x = x.str.cat(sep=" ")
    return x
df.groupby("Column1")[["Column2","Column3","Column4"]].apply(lambda x: apply_union(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of the fact that the last three columns are string type and combine them, using the [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) function, and groupby on column1, this time aggregating with python's [string join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function :

```
outcome = (df
           .set_index("Column1")
           #this helps to put space between
           #the columns when summed
           .add(' ')
           #this combines the columns into one
           .sum(axis=1)
           .str.rstrip(" ")
           .groupby("Column1")
           .agg(" ".join)
           .reset_index(name='Column2')
          )

outcome

    Column1      Column2
0   1           I am abc I do business
1   2           I am xyz I do job
2   3           on weekend holidays I do nothing
```